# How to create PyPi package with top-level functions

Tags: python, pypi

I am trying to get a package installed on PyPi and am having trouble getting it configured to have the desired syntax.  At the end of the day, I want to be able to use a function within my module using the following syntax:

```
import ucal
ucal.calculate(...)
```

This syntax follows all the common libraries.  (One could also use `from ucal import calculate`).

My directory structure is as follows:

```
ucal/
    ucal/
        __init__.py
        ucal.py
        ucal_units.py
    setup.py
```

Within ucal.py:

```
   import ucal_units
   def calculate():
       pass
```

I can upload to PyPi and then install using pip:

```
> python setup.py bdist_wheel
> python -m twine upload dist/ucal-0.1.3-py3-none-any.whl
(wait a minute)
> pip install --user ucal
```

However, inside a new script, the following script yields an error:

```
import ucal
ucal.calculate() # <-- AttributeError: module 'ucal' has no attribute 'calculate'
```

It turns out that this works instead:

```
from ucal import ucal
ucal.calculate()
```

But I don't want this silly syntax.  ucal should be at the top level.  What changes do I need to make in order to get the desired syntax to work?

I tried moving all files in ucal/ucal to the parent directory, but this resulted in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ucal'` even though the module was installed (verified with pip list)

Comment: or may be you need to add `from .ucal import calcuate` to the init file or call it like `ucal.ucal.calcuate`

Comment: I fixed the typo--that was not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In `ucal/ucal.py`, declare public names that you want to export using the [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) variable:

```
# ucal/ucal.py

__all__ = ["calculate"]

def calculate(...):
    ...
```

In `ucal/__init__.py`, pull those names up into the top-level namespace by using the * import:

```
# ucal/__init__.py

from ucal.ucal import *
```

Now, users will see `calculate` in the top-level namespace.

Answer (score 0):

When importing, the namespace within the `__init__.py` appears to be able to be accessed by the `ucal.*` syntax.  One option, then, is to replace `__init__.py` with the contents of `ucal.py`.  This doesn't seem quite correct.

Another option is to add an import statement within `__init__.py`:

```
from ucal.ucal import calculate
```

This also seems messy, but perhaps that's the accepted way to do things?